# Android UMTS tuner

Tags: android, telephony, umts

An Android device obviously has the ability to listen to EMF frequencies, otherwise it wasn't possible to make phone calls over 900mHz en 1800 mHz and what not. But the `Telephony` API only allows to address frequencies from the industry standards like 2G, 3G etc.

I'd like to scan the whole frequency range that the hardware antenna allows. I basically want to probe cellphone towers with my droid :) because the EMF scanners are pricey.

What approaches would be possible? I'm thinking about modifying a ROM but I know nothing about that yet. If that were the way to go, how would I talk to the antenna via the kernel or library?

Comment: "What approaches would be possible?" -- find an Android-powered software-defined radio (SDR) device. Then, use whatever APIs are offered by the device manufacturer to do what you seek. "I'm thinking about modifying a ROM but I know nothing about that yet" -- ROMs cannot change the capabilities of hardware.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I have been looking into SDRs following your reply. Can you elaborate more on the 2nd part of your answer? Indeed ROMs can't change the capabilities of hardware, but the hardware supports all these frequencies: 800MHz, 850MHz, 900MHz, 1800MHz , 1900MHz , 2100MHz , 2600MHz. Which makes me think it might very well be possible that the range of the hardware might be larger. Do you know anyting about that, or a direction to investigate?